# AWS Codecommit is not fetching latest commit from bitbucket

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, bitbucket, aws-codecommit

I have mirrored my bitbucket in AWS codecommit. Intially whenever I pushed code to bitbucket it is getting reflected properly on codecommit.
 But now I am not able to fetch the latest commit.

The latest commit I can see is two months back commit i.e. feb.

The only difference to previous is that IAM user role has slight changes in the access. But I am not sure how does this impacts in fetching the latest commits.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Below steps I have performed for mirroring.
Go to the **bitbucket Repository settings -> Hooks -> Enabled the Mirror hook**
and then add **mirror repo url**(codecommit repo's https url) , **username**(add IAM user and for me this user has a attached policy called "AWSCodeCommitPowerUser"), **password**  and then save the configuration
After doing this I was able to mirror the repo.
 I had perform this mirroring in May'2021.

Comment: How exactly are you doing the git repository mirroring? As far as I know that isn't a built-in feature of CodeCommit, so you must be running a script on a git commit hook or something? The details of that would be key info to include in your questoin.

Comment: @Mark B I have added the mirroring steps in the question itself